# How to catch a nodejs connect static 404 error?

Tags: node.js, static, error-handling, http-status-code-404, connect

I use nodeJS and senchalab's connect middleware (not express!!). I need to catch the static errors (like 404). How do i get these? I tried to check the source, but i could not find a way to pass an error-handler to connect.static.

here is a gist of the general structure i (have to) use:

https://gist.github.com/2397415

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your routes:

```
router.routes['/'] = 'my page';
router.routes['/404'] = '404 test';
```

I think you meant this:

```
connect()
  .use(connect.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  .use(function(req, res, next){
    switch (req.url) {
      case '/404':
        var body = '404 test';
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
        res.end(body);
        break;
      default:
        var body = 'my page';
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
        res.end(body);
    }
  })
  .listen(3001);
```

Also I want to add that in old connect version 1.x you can use 'connect.router', but in 2.x version it was [removed](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/262) and moved to express. If you need useful routing system, use express:

> Connect was never meant to be used directly, it exists to support
>   frameworks like Express

Comment: great, tnx! looks fine - i will test it asap and check the answer as solved once i got it going :)

Comment: tnx again, works nicely. actually express is a lot of overhead for me - i kind of wrote my own framework around connect for a one-page-app with a very different view system, etc.... anyways, tnx!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a catch-all routes after static and all your routes:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  //respond with 404 page or something.
})
```

It will catch all unmatched GET requests.

Comment: could you give me a short example? my router function doesn't work that way - i realize that express works like this, but i have to go without express ... 
mine looks like this: https://gist.github.com/2397415